# Redirect html page from rest web service

Tags: java, html, jsp, rest, redirect

I am new to all html and rest web service.

I have use html form in index.jsp file  which accepts the username and the password.
This form call rest web service using action attribute.

Web service authenticate the user from the username and the password provided.
Now depending upon the authentication done by web service, I have to send various pages to client's browser again.
Like for manager, employee, admin, there will different pages for each one of these. Depending on the authentication, designation is fetched from the database in web service.

I have tried with doing `Response.TemporaryRedirect(uri);` and `Response.seeOther(uri);`
But it didn't work for me.

Is there any other way to redirect page from rest web service?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I need to write the code for redirection using `Response.TemporaryRedirect(uri)`in the finnaly block. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JSP, and you have REST at the back, you can still use Servlet Filters because you are talking about a web application.

Comment: The case would have been different if you had REST services at some other locaiton, and HTML/CSS/JS at another location, and you wanted to call REST services via AJAX Jsonp or ajax with padding for cross-domain.

Comment: My web service and the html stuff is at the same location.

Comment: Does there any simple way to redirect new page, maybe from calling we service from jsp page and depending on the return value jsp can redirect the page using Response.send() function

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned earlier and as you said you have HTML and your REST service at the same location, it would be great to look at Servlet Filters... They primarily are called whenever your application REST URLs are accessed

Comment: How do servlet filters help with redirecting?

Comment: httpResponse.sendRedirect(page); and FilterChain .doFilter(request, response) would help in